# Making the height of each cell of a css grid depend on the biggest cell of his row

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm currently working on making a grid that will contain a different amount of items in each cells, and I am currently facing issues sizing the height of the cells in each rows accordingly :

I would like the height of each cell to be the same height as the biggest cell in each rows, but as it stands, the height of each cells depends on the highest cell in the entire grid.

Here's a mockup of what I currently have, notice how the while the cells in the third row are correct, the cells in the first and second row are too big.

```css
.grid {
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.grid-column {
  background-color: blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  margin: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-row {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="grid-row"></div>
    <div class="grid-row"></div>
    <div class="grid-row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="grid-row">
      <span class="item">item 1</span>
      <span class="item">item 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-row"></div>
    <div class="grid-row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="grid-row"></div>
    <div class="grid-row">
      <span class="item">item 3</span>
      <span class="item">item 4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="grid-row"></div>
    <div class="grid-row"></div>
    <div class="grid-row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="grid-row"></div>
    <div class="grid-row"></div>
    <div class="grid-row">
      <span class="item">item 5</span>
      <span class="item">item 6</span>
      <span class="item">item 7</span>
      <span class="item">item 8</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would invert the grid, starting by row then column

Comment: I'm thinking that this could work, but this layout would be the best possible outcome for this, so I want to make sure there isn't a way before switching to rows